# jQuery (advanced?) function

Tags: jquery

I have found many example jQuery code where they use multiple functions like `$('object').function1().function2()`
Can someone please explain to me how this actually works and how to properly use it?

Comment: It is called [method chaining](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_chaining.asp)

Comment: Please edit your question to show the correct syntax of what you saw. Likely `$('object').function1().function2()`

Comment: Whatever the value `$('object').function1()` returns, you can call the member functions for that returned elements with `.function2()` in the same line and so on.

Comment: Thanks. I didnt even know what it was called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming jQuery, `$(selector)` returns a jQuery collection object. jQuery defines many methods on jQuery collection object, such as `attr`, `find`, `css` or `slideUp`, which will commonly return a jQuery collection object (same or different). This is commonly called "method chaining". For example,

```js
$('div').css('background-color', 'lime').after('<div>More</div>');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>Test</div>
```

the first part, `$('div')`, returns a jQuery collection containing our single `<div>`; `.css(...)` will set its background and return the same collection; `.after(...)` will insert the new `<div>` after the first one and again return the same collection.